# Why are my buildings disappearing on minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have the pocket edition on my iPad and for some strange reason, while I'm playing, half or whole buildings of mine occasionally simply vanish.

I have looked for similar complaints everywhere but no one seems to have the same problem. I'm getting really tired of it and wish I knew why this is happening. I am also on creative mode so it has nothing to do with dying.

Comment: Is this a visual bug, as in they just disappear for a little bit and then come back; or is it a functional bug, as in the blocks themselves are gone permanently? Does it do this in the middle of playing, or when you load your world?

Comment: Once the blocks disappear, they don't come back. It also happens while I am in the game.

Comment: issssssssss it the creepersssssssss?

Comment: It's not the creepers because its on creative mode

Comment: Creepers can still blow things up in Creative.

Comment: Hmm I think it may be a bug. Since you are on creative it can't be creepers so it must be a glitch.

Answer (score 2):

How much free space do you have left on your iPad?

I'm not familiar with the way Minecraft PE stores level data, but it seems that the game is failing to commit chunks to disk properly. When the game tries to reread the chunk, it either fails to find it or finds it's corrupted and regenerates it, thus leading to vanishing portions of buildings.

(Think laying your Minecraft world in a map with latitude and longitude lines. Those lines split the map in a bunch of squares that are called "chunks" in Minecraft.)